# What is the difference between unique user counts for apps between Google analytics for Firebase and the old Google Analytics for apps?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

Can anyone explain why the unique user counts of Google Analytics for apps (before Google stopped this service) was higher than active user counts of Firebase analytics (or Google Analytics for Firebase)? I had the same app versions running on both from June 2019 to October 2019 with about a 30% different count in users.